Converting SHP to CSV in QGIS
How can I convert SHP to CSV using QGIS?
I tried online converters but they aren't for free. Free ones have limited MB.
I have a 10.3 MB zip file and it doesn't work on these online websites.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site. In order to get an Answer, the Question needs to tell us what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Please [Edit] the Question.

What should I do when someone answers my question?

Right click your layer - Export - Save Features As.


What should I do when someone answers my question?

You can save a vector file (including shp format) to other formats using the "Save vector features to file" tool located in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T).
